# Select values where array value are excluded

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I cannot find solution of such problem. I need that $sql variable shows all values except the specified values as username != $var2 array values.

```
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'blocked_emails');

    $var = $user_data['blocked_emails'];
    $var2 = explode(',', $var);

    $sql = mysqli_query($con1, "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `username` != '$var2' ORDER BY user_id");

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $uid = $row2['user_id'];
    $username = $row2['username'];
    }
```

Comment: you could try a `NOT IN (…)` instead of your `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

The core question seems to be how the SELECT statement should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `test`
  WHERE `username` NOT IN ('abc@mailinator.com', 'webmaster@test.test', …)
  ORDER BY `user_id`
```

How to produce this statement in PHP is left as an exercise to the reader. Lajos Arpad's answer gives a good start but it is safer to use a prepared statement (`$con1->prepare(…)`), so you do not have to worry about apostrophes in values, SQL injection and the like.

Answer (score 0):

As Renardo suggested, you need not in, like this:

```
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'blocked_emails');

    $var = $user_data['blocked_emails'];
    $var2 = explode(',', $var);
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($var2); $index++)
        $var2 = "'".$var2[$index]."'";

    $sql = mysqli_query($con1, "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `username` not in (".implode(",", $var2).") ORDER BY user_id");

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $uid = $row2['user_id'];
    $username = $row2['username'];
    }
```

But in this solution we assume that none of the values in `$var2` contain apostrophe. You will need to take further measures to sanitize your query, to ensure it will work well with any possible input and protect yourself against SQL injection at the same time.

Comment: Don't you need to use `[$index]` after `$var2` in your loop? And expanding `$var2` in the SELECT string yields just `Array` in my test.

Comment: @Renardo yes, I need that, forgot to add it. Thanks for pointing that out!